PyCord Slashcommands : AttributeError: type object 'Interaction' has no attribute 'respond'
Today I changed from PyCord 2.4.1 to 2.6.0 and my entire Bot broke.
I get the Error message:
Extension 'cogs.stats' raised an error: AttributeError: type object 'Interaction' has no attribute 'respond'

I send responses with await ctx.response.send_message("example").
Does anyone no what I need to change to make it work again.
Here is the main.py
import asyncio
import log_helper
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

bot = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.all(), command_prefix="$$")
log = log_helper.create("main")

bot.help_command = None

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Drachen Kult"), status=discord.Status.online)
    log("Bot ist Online!", "SUCCESS")

async def load_extensions():
    log("Lade Cogs...", "SYSTEM")
    for filename in os.listdir("cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            log(f"{filename} wird geladen!")
            try:
                await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
            except Exception as e:
                log(f"Beim Laden von {filename} ist ein Fehler aufgetreten: {e}", "CRITICAL")
    log("Alle Cogs wurden geladen!", "SUCCESS")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_dotenv()
    asyncio.run(load_extensions())
    log("Starte Bot...", "SYSTEM")
    bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

And here ist the test.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.commands import slash_command


import log_helper

log = log_helper.create("Test")
load_dotenv()

class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        Test.bot = self.bot
      

    @slash_command(name="test")
    async def restart(self, ctx):
        await ctx.respond.send_message("Test!")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))

I tested ist with ctx.respond.send_message and ctx.response.send_message and those two give the same error.

Could you please edit your question to include the full code of the command?

The Message is now edited.

Not sure if this is what you have tried, but discord.ApplicationContext, in pycord, uses await ctx.respond("Test!") to respond to slash commands.

Also, this line has no utility: ```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
Manager.bot = self.bot


Where is your 'cogs.stats' code (where the error is derived from)

To get the bot to work again, look for any usage of Interaction.respond and replace it with ctx.response.send_message()
It could also help to read PyCord 2.6.0 documentation :)
Try this
@bot.slash_command(name=“example”)
 async def example(ctx):
 await
 ctx.response.send_message(“Example is working!”)

Test it out and I hope you will get your bot to work again

Not every slash command uses the ctx object. Some buttons and other classes use Interaction. Also, having "It could also help to read PyCord 2.6.0 documentation :)" can be seen as condescending. Refrain from doing that.
Your code block has indentation issues as well.
